# What is the value of unexisting property

Tags: php

I have installed Magento and PrestaShop on my local computer. I wrote 2 modules (for presta and magento and they have the same core). The problem is error_reporting. Let me give you an example.
Magento

```
@ini_set('display_errors', 'on');
@error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
$obj = new Obj();
var_dump($obj->version); //returns null because the property "version" doesn't really exist
die();
```

Presta

```
$obj = new Obj();
var_dump($obj->version); //returns E_NOTICE error because the property "version" doesn't really exist
```

Why Magento returns null while Presta throws error. What can cause such a behavior?

Comment: Didn't you just answer your own question? It's to do with the `error_reporting` setting...

Comment: well, I added "ini_set('display_errors', 'on'); error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);" just before "$obj->version" in Magento and no errors showed.

Answer (score 2):

php settings. if you have it set for showing `E_NOTICE` it will show the notice. The first probably "has" the notice as well, but you didn't set your system to show it

Please see [this reference question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php) for more information about errors

Answer (score 1):

Errors can be handles and inside a framework there are checks in place that are assuring a certain quality of code. Your property may exist, but it may be not visible in a certain context - like private properties. In your Obj there may be an overloading function like [__get()](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.get) that handles the return in case values are not there or they don't correspond to some other logic.